# $_SESSION['pseudo'] = null while it clearly shouldn't

Tags: php, session, header, isset

Let me explain : I got 3 pages (One to login, a transitional page, and my main page once you are logged.)
So I want prevent access of my app because if you deconnect your session, and then you return back, you still have access to the website even if your session if off. So that's why I want to use `!isset($_SESSION['pseudo'])`.

1st page :

```php
<form method="post" action="<?php echo serverRoot; ?>?action=connect">
    <input required class="input-login" name="pseudo" type="text" id="pseudo" placeholder="Login">
    <input required class="input-login" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="connect" type="submit" value="Connect" />
</form>
```

So as you can see, once submited, we got the action "connect".

Here the case of "connect":

```php
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {

    switch ($_GET['action']) {

    case 'connect':
            {
                showPage(adresseRoot . 'PHP/View/', 'FormConnection.php', "Connection");
                break;
            }
```

2nd page :

```php
$user = UserManager::getByPseudo($_POST['pseudo']);

if ($user->getPassword() === 'md5'.md5($_POST['password'].$_POST['pseudo']))
    {
        $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $user->getLogin();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user->getIdUtilisateur();
        $message = '<p>Welcome ' . $user->getLogin() . ', !</p>';
        echo $message;
        header("refresh:3;url=Paths.php?action=listMenu");
    }
```

As you can see `$_SESSION['pseudo']` is now isset. It's not NULL !
And then you have `header("refresh:3;url=Paths.php?action=listMenu")`

```php
case 'listMenu':
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['pseudo'])){

        showPage(adresseRoot . 'PHP/View/', 'FormConnection.php', "Connection"); //You don't have the right to go to the Website
        break;

    }
    else{
        showPage(adresseRoot . 'PHP/View/', 'ListMenu.php', "Main page"); //You have the right to go to the Website
        break;
    }
}
```

The fact is, when I enter the right logins, I'm redirected to the connection page, not on my Main page... Wtf?

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Are you using `session_start()` in all the pages?

Comment: Don't `echo` (display) anything before changing the header. Displaying something will send header and you can't change it anymore

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman yes I do, in all the pages.

Comment: @Cid but what could I do ? I need to specify that  `$_SESSION['pseudo'] = $user->getLogin();` before `header("refresh:3;url=Routes.php?action=listMenu");` ....

Comment: @Ashka Well, do it, but avoid **displaying** something before modifying the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found.

I've added `session_start()` at the top of Paths.php.

& I've deleted the `session_start()` of all other pages.